# Launch file for package not running with rosrun

Tags: ros, catkin-package, rosrun, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am making a package to communicate with an Arduino that I have on my robot to control it. I have the package on github [here.](https://github.com/kk6axq/ros_arduino_bridge) When I run  `rosrun ros_arduino_python arduino.launch` I get the following error:

> /home/lukas/catkin_ws/install/share/ros_arduino_python/ros_arduino_python/launch/arduino.launch: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' /home/lukas/catkin_ws/install/share/ros_arduino_python/ros_arduino_python/launch/arduino.launch: line 1:` '

Sorry about the formatting, I gues ros like using the little backwards quotes...
Anyway, here is my launch file, arduino.launch:

```
     <launch>
     <node name="arduino" pkg="ros_arduino_python"
 type="arduino_node.py"
 output="screen">
     <rosparam file="$(find ros_arduino_python)/config/my_arduino_params.yaml"
 command="load" />
     </node>
     </launch>
```

The rest of the code is on github. I am only 13 so the more help I can get the better.
Thanks,
L

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204812/launch-file-for-package-not-running-with-rosrun/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the command

```
roslaunch ros_arduino_python arduino.launch
```

The `rosrun` command is for starting individual nodes and the `roslaunch` command is for kicking off launch files.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-03-12**:
Thanks for the answer, that solved it. I also found that I needed to `chmod +x` the python file so it would execute...
Thanks,
L